# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - Python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to save user inputs into a file but I keep getting a TypeError. How do I fix it

```
from passenger import *

file = open("passenger.txt", 'w')

continue_record = True
while continue_record:
    record = input("\nRecord passenger (y/n): ")
    if record == 'n':
        continue_record = False
    else:

        distance, name, passenger_type = input_passenger()

        total_fare = compute(distance)
        get_receipt = receipt(name,passenger_type, distance, total_fare)

        file.write(get_receipt)
        file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

This is my input_passenger function:

```
def input_passenger():
    global distance
    global passenger_name
    global passenger_type

    passenger_name = input("Enter your name: ")
    distance = float(input("Enter distance: "))
    passenger_type = input("Enter type of passenger: ")

    return passenger_name, distance, passenger_type #I tried returning them but it gives me this error
```

Error:

```
line 14, in <module>
    total_fare = compute(distance)

line 29, in compute
    if distance > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

This is my code in compute function

```
def compute(distance):
    global fare
    fare = 0
    if distance > 0:
        fare += 3 * 50
        fare += (distance - 3) * 4.5
    else:
        fare = round(distance * 50, 2)

    return fare
```

I tried converting it, but it still the error

Comment: Post complete traceback error.

Comment: Hello @Bhargav. This is the complete traceback error line 12, in <module>
    distance, name, passenger_type = input_passenger()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: `input_passenger()` does not have a `return` statement, so it returns `None` by default.  I think you meant to have `return passenger_name, distance, passenger_type` at the end of that function.

Comment: `input` returns a string. In  `input_passenger` you return that `passenger_name` and assign it to `distance`, and hence your program crashes when you treat `distance` as a number when it's a sting. Your code is a mess; don't use `global` in `input_passenger`, fix the order of the returned values so that caller and called function agree, and finally cast any strings to int before comparing them to ints.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the elements in a different order of unpacking them.

```py
return passenger_name, distance, passenger_type
```

You unpack as the following (note that distance is actually the passenger_name).

```py
distance, name, passenger_type = input_passenger()
```

You want

```py
name, distance, passenger_type = input_passenger()
```

But yes like what others have said you likely want to avoid globals whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

line 29, in compute
if distance > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

**Distance is a string while you are supposed to convert it into an integer.**
if int(distance) > 0:

```
fare += 3 * 50
    fare += int(distance - 3)) * 4.5
else:
    fare = round(int(distance * 50, 2))
return fare
```